# Is there any way to specify a variablename in df.loc keyword?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am making a revenue forecast model wherein, there is one column that i require is dependent upon the current month and is a variable.

I have marked the variables as curr_month as user input. Depending upon this, i have also derived another variable rem_month for remaining months.

Now, the column that i need to create is summation of remaining columns except current month. Also, the input columns change as per follows:

```py
Jan-May: Planned
June-October: Mid
November: Final
December: Planned for next year.
```

I created a list for each month as follows:

```py
Revenue_Jan = ['P_2019_Feb','P_2019_Mar','P_2019_Apr','P_2019_May','P_2019_Jun','P_2019_Jul','P_2019_Aug','P_2019_Sep','P_2019_Oct','P_2019_Nov','P_2019_Dec']
Revenue_Feb = ['P_2019_Mar','P_2019_Apr','P_2019_May','P_2019_Jun','P_2019_Jul','P_2019_Aug','P_2019_Sep','P_2019_Oct','P_2019_Nov','P_2019_Dec']
Revenue_Mar = ['P_2019_Apr','P_2019_May','P_2019_Jun','P_2019_Jul','P_2019_Aug','P_2019_Sep','P_2019_Oct','P_2019_Nov','P_2019_Dec']
Revenue_Apr = ['P_2019_May','P_2019_Jun','P_2019_Jul','P_2019_Aug','P_2019_Sep','P_2019_Oct','P_2019_Nov','P_2019_Dec']
Revenue_May = ['P_2019_Jun','P_2019_Jul','P_2019_Aug','P_2019_Sep','P_2019_Oct','P_2019_Nov','P_2019_Dec']
Revenue_Jun = ['M_2019_Jul','M_2019_Aug','M_2019_Sep','M_2019_Oct','M_2019_Nov','M_2019_Dec']
Revenue_Jul = ['M_2019_Aug','M_2019_Sep','M_2019_Oct','M_2019_Nov','M_2019_Dec']
Revenue_Aug = ['M_2019_Sep','M_2019_Oct','M_2019_Nov','M_2019_Dec']
Revenue_Sep = ['M_2019_Oct','M_2019_Nov','M_2019_Dec']
Revenue_Oct = ['M_2019_Nov','M_2019_Dec']
Revenue_Nov = ['F_2019_Nov','F_2019_Dec']
Revenue_Dec = ['P_2020_Jan','P_2020_Feb','P_2020_Mar','P_2020_Apr','P_2020_May','P_2020_Jun','P_2020_Jul','P_2020_Aug','P_2020_Sep','P_2020_Oct','P_2020_Nov','P_2020_Dec']
```

Now, i am planing to create a final column "Landing" which will be sum of all the columns mentioned in the specific list as per the currert monmth.

```py
#var="Revenue_"+ curr_month
#print (var)

--> Revenue_Sep
```

Now i plan to use df.loc:

```py
#df['Landing']= df.loc[:,Revenue_Sep].sum(axis=1)
```

And this gives me correct output.

But in case i decide to use variable it fails stating "Revenue_Sep column not defined in dataframe"

```py
#df['Landing']= df.loc[:,var].sum(axis=1)       #Need help with this.
```

Since rest of my model is completely ready, i just need help with this final statement so that i need not go making changes for entire model again.

Comment: Probably you want: var=globals()["Revenue_"+ curr_month]

Comment: Thanks, could you provide a bit more clarity on this? 
The variable "var" is getting properly assigned in my scenario but how do i use it in df.loc so that it will be universal and i don't have to change it every month manually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Comment: Use my "var" assignment instead of yours and then use your last code snippet as it is: df['Landing']= df.loc[:,var].sum(axis=1)

Comment: Wow !!! this is awesome. How did you do that? It works perfectly for my scenario :)

Comment: "globals()" returns a dictionary of the defined global variables like the "Revenue_..." variables.

Comment: @MichaelButscher: Appreciate your comments !!!